# Angular JS not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ma learning and its my first day to angular js ! though I have learned how model-controller-views works in `angular js`,the fowllowing code not showing the variables,instead it gives normal {{}} `HTML` views without `ng-repeat` working :

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <title>Your Shopping Cart</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller='CartController'>
        <h1>Your Order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
            <span>{{item.title}}</span>
            <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
            <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
        <script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            function CartController($scope) {
                $scope.items = [
                    {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                    {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                    {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
                ];
                $scope.remove = function(index) {
                    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define your `myApp` module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('CartController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
        {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
        {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
    ];
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
}]);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrD9M/1)</kbd>

Comment: +1 for teaching how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 5):

Just replace

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```

with

```
<html ng-app>
```

and it should work.

With ng-app='myApp' you tell angularjs that you have a module called myApp. But you define no module.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you didn't define `module` in controller.

```
<script>
 angular.module('myApp', []);  // add this line

        function CartController($scope) {
            $scope.items = [
                {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
            ];
            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Your Demo in <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rmwbPG6Cv2AnL78vzRxb?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: "module" not "model."